# Twilio Update Outgoing caller ID

Tags: ruby, twilio, twilio-api

Trying to update an outgoing caller ID, but running into following error:

```
*** Twilio::REST::RestError Exception: Unable to fetch record: The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts/AC...../OutgoingCallerIds/CA......json was not found
```

I'm following the docs on Twilio's website:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/outgoing-caller-ids#get-outgoing-caller-id-details

```
@caller_id = @client.account
                .outgoing_caller_ids('PNe905d7e6b410746a0fb08c57e5a186f3')
                .fetch
```

What string do I need to pass to .outgoing_caller_ids?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Outgoing caller IDs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/outgoing-caller-ids) are verified numbers that you can use as a caller ID when you're making calls from your account.

I was able to fetch an outgoing caller ID with the following code:

```
sid = client.outgoing_caller_ids.list.first.sid
caller_id = client.outgoing_caller_ids(sid).fetch
```

My guess is that you are actually looking for the [Incoming Phone Numbers resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers), which is the resource you can use to fetch and update numbers that you bought on the Twilio platform.

You can call that with the number SID like this:

```
client.incoming_phone_numbers(sid).fetch
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: that works, thank you. Do you also know how I can create/update an Outgoing Caller ID for a sub account?

Comment: If you want to do things for subaccounts you can fetch the account object and then use it to perform the actions. `account = client.accounts(account_sid).fetch ; account.validation_requests.create(phone_number: phone_number)`.

Comment: So for creating a messaging service for a sub account I would do 
`@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(account_sid, auth_token)
sub_account = @client.api.accounts.create(friendly_name: friendly_name)
service = sub_account.messaging.v1.services.create(friendly_name: "#{friendly_name}")`